# if future date is set on a DAG, manual run is not possible in airflow 1.10.1

Tags: python, celery, airflow, airflow-scheduler

In an earlier version of Airflow 1.8 our team was able to run DAGs manually even if the start_date was set to a future date. This is now not happening after we upgraded Airflow to 1.10.1 with a Cluster setup using *celery*.

Has anything changed between the versions of Airflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a [changelog](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/CHANGELOG.txt) available for reference and the apache jira for the project airflow can show you all the those tickets which will have comments for their github pull requests. You can review changes in each pull request, or you can take a [look at the diff in tags](https://github.com/apache/airflow/compare/1.8.0..1.10.1). You're probably interested in the scheduler changes, as that would be what checks if a task can be scheduled, though it might be in the celery executor or job runner that double-checks.

It sort of looks like the [intent](https://github.com/apache/airflow/compare/1.8.0..1.10.1#diff-54a57ccc2c8e73d12c812798bf79ccb2L814) was not to run jobs dated in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says you can run dags with a future execution date.

Must enable the `allow_trigger_in_future` flag in `airflow.cfg` though

```
allow_trigger_in_future
New in version 1.10.8.

Allow externally triggered DagRuns for Execution Dates in the future Only has effect if schedule_interval is set to None in DAG

Type
string

Default
False

Environment Variable
AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__ALLOW_TRIGGER_IN_FUTURE
```

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#allow-trigger-in-future